# What does gsmAccess() function do (GSM.h and Arduino)

Tags: arduino, gsm

I have a module which connects and sends ussd through arduino+GSM shield. I am kind of fuzzy on the following two commands which are commented with `??`. (line 4 and line 7).

Can someone explain what these two do?

And plus `gsmAccess.getStatus() == 3`; what are the other values that this function can return apart from `3`?

```
#include <GSM.h>
#include <GSM3ShieldV1DirectModemProvider.h>
GSM3ShieldV1DirectModemProvider modemAccess;
GSM gsmAccess(true);                           // ??

void sendCommand(String com){                 // com is "AT+CUSD=1,\"#366#\",\0"
  if(gsmAccess.getStatus() == 3)              // ??
    Serial.println(modemAccess.writeModemCommand(com,comDelay));
  else{
    connectModule();
    sendCommand(com);
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
GSM gsmAccess(true);
```

initializes the GSM library to enable an Arduino to act as though it were a mobile (cell) phone. The `true` parameter puts the library into debug mode which will print out all the AT commands from the modem ([reference](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/GSMConstructor)).

The line:

```
if (gsmAccess.getStatus() == 3)
```

is checking that the GSM library is ready to send commands. The `3` is the code for `GSM_READY` [as defined in the source code](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/db8cbf24c99dc930b9ccff1a43d018c81f178535/libraries/GSM/src/GSM3MobileAccessProvider.h)

For clarity it would be better to write this line as:

```
if (gsmAccess.getStatus() == GSM_READY)
```

The other statuses (defined in the same source file) are:

```
0: ERROR
1: IDLE
2: CONNECTING
3: GSM_READY
4: GPRS_READY
5: TRANSPARENT_CONNECTED
6: OFF
```

Comment: That was excellent. Thank you for the to the point clear explanation.